# Should i allow user to use the admin panel to upload his blog?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm building an app for someone, one of its function is it allowers the owner to upload blogs to the website.
So i'm wondering if i should create a page for uploading blog or just give him staff permission so he can create and upload it through django's admin panel.

I want to know if this is safe or if it will be worth it to create a front-end template for just one person to use.

Comment: I would create a front-end template. It does not take to much time. And you can specify all your input fields. It just makes a more professional impression as with the admin panel.

Comment: I will go for the template, but like @Ahmed said changing the admin url to something random like: 'arwiegb2@dfr$0 ' is ok right?

Comment: It is fine to chance the path to something randomly, but I don't think that it is going to be necessary. Just chose a path you can remember like `path('yourappname-adminpage/', admin.site.urls),`

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on a lot of things but I will say my opinion on some scenarios:

best practices: ya for sure you have to create a full template page with decorators that allow only staff account to access just like the admin, also don't ever depend on the admin panel even if you wanted a dashboard for an admin just create customized admin template, also some developer just remove the default admin panel on deploy, or may be make the end point of the admin panel instead of '/admin' they make something like that 'SAF#saf$%OIL>$/' to hide it for security

If it works leave it : if we are talking here on simple ecommerce app ya its fine just make a staff account for the owner so he could access the admin panel its fine
if you want to add permissions to the owner account use groups and add the account you created for the admin to this group then go to groups table and add what table should users of this group have access to it's totally fine
only make a customized admin panel when you need more functionality and visualization